# Is it possible to have a function call as the body of a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is it possible to have a function executed in a different thread by just calling that function in the body of the thread I have defined?

```
Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
   }
});
background.start();
```

Can I do something like this?

Comment: Yes you can do that and it will run in a separate thread.

Comment: Depends if `mCamera` is declared as final.

Comment: Data also must be final.

Comment: `mCamera` does not need to be final, because it is a class variable.

Answer (score 5):

Provided `mCamera` and `data` are instance members, static members or final variables and non-null this should work.

Comment: +1, Good job covering the cases variables can be referenced under.

Comment: to be complete; `data` could be null depending on how `addCallbackBuffer` uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes why not, if you have the object you can invoke it's method in any thread.